# Calculate exponential value in Gravity Forms

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I've been looking at the documentation of the program and can not find the option to perform exponential operations.

Is there any way?, Maybe with a script?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculation field formulas don't currently support exponents so you're going to need to use the gform_calculation_result JavaScript hook along with JavaScript [pow()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pow.asp) and jQuery [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to override the result of the formula.

If your calculation field id was 2 and you wanted to calculate the value entered in field 1 to the power of 3 your script could look like this

```
<script>
gform.addFilter( 'gform_calculation_result', function(result, formulaField, formId, calcObj ){    
    if ( formulaField.field_id == "2" ){
        var num = jQuery('#input_10_1').val();
        result = Math.pow(num, 3);
    }
    return result;
});
</script>
```

Comment: But where I put the code? Insert Into an HTML form field and paste the script?
I created a new form, with 2 fields and other HTML field, I have put the code in and no calculation is performed:
The id fields are you the next:

Form, ID=6
Numeric Field 1, ID=1
Numeric Field 2, ID=2
HTML field ID=3

<script>
gform.addFilter ('gform_calculation_result', function (result, FormulaField, formId, calcObj){
     if(formulaField.field_id == "2"){
         var num = jQuery ('# input_6_1') val ().;
         result = Math.pow (num, 3);
     }
     return result;
});
</ script>
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code can be placed in a HTML field on the form. Does your calculation field also include a basic formula to activate the calculation functions.

If you continue to have issues I would recommend opening a ticket over on the support site: http://www.gravityhelp.com/support/

Comment: You are great! Now I can use your script. 

I missed to enable the field with ID = 2 check "Enable calculation"

Thanks a lot!